# Swift declarar una función dentro de otra al estilo Pascal

Tags: ios, swift

¿ Es posible en Swift declarar una función dentro de otra para que esa función solo exista dentro de su función ? Por ejemplo como se puede hacer en lenguaje Pascal.

He declarado la función dentro y el compilador no me da warning ni aviso de error como si se pudiera hacer. Pero a la hora de llamarla parece que el compilador no la reconoce.

¿ Si es posible hacerlo que limitaciones tiene ?

Ejemplo:

```
@IBAction func pressButton(_ sender: Any) {
    func funcion2() {
       // codigo 2
    }

    // codigo 1

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, es posible declarar funciones dentro de funciones y que solo existan para la "función padre" por así decir.

Puede que esto te ayude a entender como funcionan:
[What is the benefit of nesting functions (in general/in Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354534/what-is-the-benefit-of-nesting-functions-in-general-in-swift)

Comment: Ok, como pense se usa para organizar el código. Para llamarlo se llama   simplemente con el nombre que se ha declarado dentro y esta función anidada puede ver la variables locales de la función padre sin hacer falta pasarle los parametros.

Comment: ¿ Sería posible llamarla desde otra funcion que no sea la función padre ?

Comment: @Popularfan las funciones declaradas adentro de una función, son funciones locales para la función padre. Es decir, no se pueden llamar dentro de otra función. Si deseas hacer esto mejor declarala como una función independiente

Comment: @PabloMarrufo ok gracias tambien por la aclaración

Comment: @Popularfan por nada